Array of Objects not getting reflecting in LWC html
I have an array of objects & some objects have child objects/child array of objects as well within that.
I have few checkboxes on the LWC html on every row. When checkboxes are clicked (based on the nature of the checkbox selected & which level it is checked/unchecked) i.e whether it is clicked on the Parent or child object or childs child object, I update the array of objects which is iterated in html.
When I do a console.log in JS & print the complete array after updating the objects, all object elements has the correct values, however it is not reflecting in the html.
I am updating these objects within the array, by find (array.find) the specific object and updating the values of the object elements, in this case the updated object array is not reflected in the html. However if use array.map & loop through every record and reconstruct the whole array, then it is reflecting in html.
I don't want to do this, as my array has huge number of records, and every time we click it, it rebuilds the entire object array using map and which in turn takes times on the screen.
I have used getter & setter for the array of objects, but still not reflecting in html
Is there a way to refresh the Array in html, whenever there is an update to it in JS without reconstructing entire object array using map in JS

Without code I cannot say for sure, but it sounds like you should review the Reactivity docs; if you have nested objects in an array, you likely need to use @track to make the whole array reactive.

Thank you so much.. Adding @track to the entire array did the trick..
